# Secrets in Compose: Environment variable has file path as value instead of its content

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I'm trying to use [Secrets with Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/use-secrets/#advanced)

Here is my Docker Compose (only the relevant parts):

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  My-Service:
    build:
      context: ./..
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    image: my-app/api
    container_name: my-app-api
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Docker
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:8080
      Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret_FILE: /run/secrets/my_secret
    secrets:
      - my_secret
    ports:
      - "50002:8080"

secrets:
  my_secret:
    file: ./my_secret.txt
```

I have a `my_secret.txt` file containing a secret.

Then I create the image and run it

```bash
docker compose -f ./docker/compose.yaml -p my-app up -d --build
```

Inside the container, checking the `/run/secrets/my_secret` file is here and has the correct value

```bash
sh-5.1$ cat /run/secrets/my_secret
My super secret
```

The only problem is that my `Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret_FILE` environment variable has the value of my file path instead of its content

```bash
sh-5.1$ echo $Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret_FILE
/run/secrets/my_secret
```

So what am I doing wrong here?
I think I'm doing exactly like the Docker documentation says, yet it doesn't work as intended. I honestly can't wrap my head around this.

Thanks for your answer(s).

Comment: who sets `Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret` variable? (from `Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret_FILE`) ...the developers of mysql/wordpress official docker images have considered this aspect `_FILE` vs "actual value", since you have a custom dockerfile, who should consider it?;)

Comment: @xerx593 thanks for your comment. I didn't really understand your point at first but now I get it. I wrote an answer with my solution

Comment: sorry for my confusing/non-native writing, but you got me exactly right! :-) ..here's how they handle it at mysql (official docker image;): https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L28

Comment: and the linked article/reference (compose secrets) also "notes" (somewhat cryptic) "Note
The `_FILE` environment variables demonstrated here are a convention used by *some* images, including Docker Official Images like mysql and postgres."

Comment: @xerx593 Thanks for the link ! I'll copy their code I think. Much cleaner than mine. And yeah I saw about the note at the end of the file right after posting my question here. But I thought because I'm using the .NET Docker image from Microsoft, somehow it would just work out of the box. I was wrong (I don't have much experience with Docker).

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally got something working even if it's not as clean as I'd like.

My mistake was assuming that my environment variable `Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret_FILE` would "magically" have its value set to the content of my `/run/secrets/my_secret` file but there's no such kind of automatic magic, it has to be manually set.

Here is my new Docker Compose file

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  My-Service:
    build:
      context: ./..
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    image: my-app/api
    container_name: my-app-api
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Docker
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:8080
      Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret_FILE: /run/secrets/my_secret
    secrets:
      - my_secret
    ports:
      - "50002:8080"
    entrypoint: ./compose-entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      # $FINAL_WORKDIR is an environment variable set in the .env file with the path of the final WORKDIR set in the Dockerfile before executing the ENTRYPOINT
      - "./compose-entrypoint.sh:$FINAL_WORKDIR/compose-entrypoint.sh:ro"

secrets:
  my_secret:
    file: ./my_secret.txt
```

The changes are:

- It now overrides the `ENTRYPOINT` directive from the `Dockerfile` and execute a `compose-entrypoint.sh` file instead
- It mounts the `compose-entrypoint.sh` file in a volume (as read-only with `:ro`) so it can be executed as the entrypoint (make sure the file is *executable* on your host machine so it *will be* executable as well in your container)

The logic to set the `Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret` environement variable I need happens in this `compose-entrypoint.sh` file:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

export Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret=$(cat $(echo $Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret_FILE))
source ./entrypoint.sh
```

*Note: I kept this file as simple as possible to better demonstrate the basis principle. However a better way is simply to copy how [MySQL is doing](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L28) (thanks to @xerx593 who shared the link in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77955182/secrets-in-compose-environment-variable-has-file-path-as-value-instead-of-its-c/77956270#comment137434003_77955182))*

This script is:

1. Getting the value of the `Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret_FILE` environment variable which is actually a file path
2. Read the content of this file
3. Set a `Swagger__Authentication__ClientSecret` environment variable with the content read from the file
4. Call the `entrypoint.sh` file that is the original file called in the `Dockerfile`

At the end of my `Dockerfile` I just had to copy the `entrypoint-sh` bash file and make it executable

```bash
COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Note that by default it is executing the `entrypoint.sh` file which is NOT setting any additional environment variable. The `compose-entrypoint.sh` file is executed only when using Docker Compose.

Hope this could clarify some obscure parts.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine your first example (the one that works). You execute this command : `cat /run/secrets/my_secret` and you get result `My super secret`.

The `cat` command reads a file at the provided path and print its content. Thus, your command reads the file at `/run/secrets/my_secret` and print its content which is `My super secret`.

Now, let's examine the second one. You execute this command `echo $Swagger_Authentication_ClientSecret` and get this result `/run/secrets/my_secret`.

`$Swagger_Authentication_ClientSecret` is the value saved in the variable `Swagger_Authentication_ClientSecret`. You did set this variable in the environment of your container to be `/run/secrets/my_secret`. You execute `echo` with this value as parameter. `echo` simply prints the value given as parameter. Your command then print the value stored in your variable.

What you want is to print the content of the file whose path is the value stored in your variable. To do so, just replace `echo` with `cat` in your second command